# jQuery Load Function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I want to load data from Database. "output" has to be loaded which contains some data about the coordinates of Geofence and be added to the map. Here is the load Function:

```
           jQuery("#submitButtonLoad").click(function () {

                /*the jQuery.ajax gets openend*/
                jQuery.ajax({
                    /*typ POST gets defined*/
                    type: "POST",
                    /*the PHP file that receives the POST*/
                    url: "parsernew.php",
                    /*the data that gets transfered*/


                    success: function(html){ //so, if data is retrieved, store it in html

                    var vectorOutput = jQuery("#output").val();
                    var vectorName = jQuery("#vectorName").val();

                    jQuert('#output').html();

                    }
                }); //close jQuery.ajax(
            });
```

This is also parsernew.php which get required data from database. The connection is done by using config.php:

```
 <?php    
 session_start();    
 print_r($_SESSION);    

 /*if the id parameter is not set an error occures*/     
 if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {      
 /*ajax request/abfrage, check.....*/      
 echo 'the user id is missing';     
 die();     
 }     
 /*if the id parameter is set else gets executed*/     
 else     
 {     
 /*the id of the user gets requested*/     
 $id=$_SESSION['id'];     
 /*the parameters get requested and saved into local variables*/     
 $vector      = ($_POST['vector']);     
 $name        = ($_POST['name']);     
 echo $id;     
 echo $vector;     
 echo $geofence;     
 /*the config.in.php is called*/     
 /*this programms opens the conncetion to the database*/     
 include('config.php');       
 /*the SELECT query gets created*/      
 $eintrag = "SELECT (geofencename,geometry,fk_user_geofence) VALUES ('$name','$vector','$id') FROM public.geofence";      

/*the above mentioned query gets executed      
--> this always executes a query, no matter what kind */      
$eintragen = pg_query($eintrag);     

/*if the query is not correct an error occures*/     
 if (!$eintrag) {      
        die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());       
  }          
 }      
?>
```

Can anybody please tell me where is the problem? I need to load output on map.

This part is edited. This is my Save function which I wanted to program Load function based on that:

```
      /* SAVE BUTTON */
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

             /*if the submit Button gets clicked this function is called*/
            jQuery("#submitButton").click(function () {

                /*the text of the html field output and vectorName are stored into javascript variables 
                vectorOutput 
                VectorName*/
                var vectorOutput = jQuery("#output").val();
                var vectorName = jQuery("#vectorName").val();

                /*the jQuery.ajax gets openend*/
                jQuery.ajax({
                    /*typ POST gets defined*/
                    type: "POST",
                    /*the PHP file that receives the POST*/
                    url: "parser22.php",
                    /*the data that gets transfered*/
                    data: {
                        /*vector: contains the geometric information of the overlay, in kml format*/
                        vector: vectorOutput,

                        /*name: contains the chosen name of the geofence*/
                        name: vectorName
                    },
                    success: function(html){ //so, if data is retrieved, store it in html
                        /*if the save button gets clicked the field with the geofencename */
                        jQuery("#output").val('');
                        /*and kml koordinates get emptied*/
                        jQuery("#vectorName").val('');
                        /*to show the user that it worked alert Window pops up*/
                        alert("Geofence successfully saved!");
                    }
                }); //close jQuery.ajax(
            });
      //  });
```

Comment: Are you sure your select query is working??

Comment: **"output" has to be loaded which contains some data about the coordinates of Geofence and be added to the map**. What does that mean? **"so, if data is retrieved, store it in html"** AND DO NOTHING WITH IT.

Comment: I am not sure I just thought that SELECT FROM might work. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: The statement just does not make sense. That's all I am saying; maybe it's just me.

Comment: It is possible that we draw shaped with polygon on map. These data saved in output and they are saved in database. Now I want to load them that when a user refresh the page, he can have the previous shape which he draw by clicking on load button.

Comment: Can you provide your markup (HTML) so we can see `#output` and other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Does the database user that is executing the query have appropriate privileges to read? Also I am assuming the following is a typo here only and not in your running code?

```
jQuert('#output').html();
```

EDIT 1:

It is difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.  btw it is more flexible and preferred do something like this with done instead of success:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
       // config
  }).done(function(data){
       // do something with data
       jQuery('#output').html(data);
  });
```

EDIT 2:

Looking at the example CRUD link in the comments below, the structure of how the load versus save operations are layed out is basically what I am deducing from what you are trying to achieve. The post method is just a more specific method so replace it with ajax if needed. Try to commit to the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle as much as possible with your code. In this case a common load method could be used initially and then after your save method is invoked.

Comment: Then what should be in success:function instead of that? I have edited my question and added save function which works. I wanted to create load function based on save function.

Comment: Does this help in any way?

Comment: var vectorOutput = jQuery("#output").val();      jQuert("#output").html(vectorOutput);      I changed everything as you said.But unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/05/crud-with-php-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

The code inside `success` makes no sense. And even if it would, there is a typo: **jQuert**. I guess you want something like:

```
success: function(html){
            var foo = doSomething(html);
            jQuery('#output').html(foo);
         }
```

Comment: I have just edited my Question and add Save function as well. Could you based on that guide me more accurate that what should be in succes:function?

Comment: No sorry, I don´t understand what you are trying to do. Obviously you want to use the received `html` in some way, but right now you are only clearing some fields.

Comment: Then how can I load OUTPUT based on my save function?

Comment: You want to put content into `output`? And that content is the received data from the database?

Comment: In this project it is possible that we draw shaped with polygon on the map. These drawn shapes which are data, saved in output and they are saved in database by clicking save button. Now I want to load them that when a user refresh the page, he can have the previous shape on the map which he draw by clicking on load button.

Comment: I give up. Sorry. I have no idea what you mean.